# Running functions in sequence

Tags: sprite-kit

I am trying to make a game that starts after a 3 second delay. So I am trying to add a sequence, so that the startGame function is called in a sequence after a delay. I can then call that function with the delay included at the beginning, but I keep getting an error when I try the run the sequence at the end of the second function.

I have the start game function:

```
 func startGame(){
    let spawn = SKAction.run(createEnemy)
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
    let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence)
    self.run(spawnForever)
}
```

and then I have another function that uses that function in a sequence to add a delay.

```
 func beginGame(){
    let countdown = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let startGame = SKAction.run(self.startGame)
    let startSequence = SKAction.sequence([countdown, startGame])
    **self.beginGame().run(startSequence)**
}
```

I then call the beginGame() function at the along with the setup function. along with the setup function at the end.

```
scene.setup()
scene.beginGame()
```

I am getting an "Value of tuple '()' has no member 'run'"

Sorry for the stupid question, I'm a beginner at swift.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let spawn = SKAction.run { self.createEnemy() }
```

and

```
let startGame = SKAction.run { self.startGame() }
```

run block is a closure so it might need the brackets

try this...

```
func startGame() -> SKAction {
    let spawn = SKAction.run { self.hello() }
    let wait = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 2)
    let spawnSequence = SKAction.sequence([wait, spawn])
    let spawnForever = SKAction.repeatForever(spawnSequence)

    return spawnForever
}

func beginGame() {

    let countdown = SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3)
    let startGame = self.startGame()
    let startSequence = SKAction.sequence([countdown, startGame])
}

self.beginGame()
```

Comment: I changed it around a bit return an SKAction from StartGame() give that a try

Answer (score 0):

SKActions should be run on a node. Your line of code 
`self.beginGame().run(startSequence)` appears to be trying to run your sequence on the function `beginGame()`. Because `beginGame()`which does not have a defined return type.

According to https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html

> Functions without a defined return type return a special value of type
>   Void. This is simply an empty tuple, which is written as ().

and as the compiler is telling you, you cannot use `run` on a tuple.